# VS 2012 Standalone Profiler doesn't create vsp file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, profiler, symbols

This is my first time with the vs standalone profiler, so I started of with the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385771.aspx) way of making it work.

When I run VSInstr I get the following result:

```
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 12.0.31101 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Usage: VSInstr [/U] filename [options]
```

Which suggest that I have set it up correctly. Then I've right clicked my computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Eviroment Variables

I've added a new variable with the name _NT_SYMBOL_PATH and value symsrv*symsrv.dll*c:\localcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

But when I run the following command:

```
>vsperfreport c:\localcache\somefile.vsp /summary:all /packsymbols
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) VSPerf Report Generator, Version 12.0.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Error VSP1710: File not found: c:\localcache\somefile.vsp
Error: VSP1804: Did not successfully open the file.
```

So the file really isn't there as it says, but I thought the file should be created automatically?
The other thing I feel I should mention is that I'm doing this on a Windows 7 VM, but I don't think that should be an issue.

**EDIT:**

I started with a different approach, but now I have a different issue...

these are the steps I'm doing in order to try and performance test my application.

start cmd line:

1)set path=%path%;c:...\Performance tools\

2)vsinstre.exe my application <- this creates an instrumented version of my application exe (as far as I know I need an instrumented application to be able to trace it)

3)Open up developer command, I need to resign my application because it is strongly typed, so I do the steps descriped [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnls/archive/2005/12/30/508321.aspx)

4)back in cmd > vsperfclrenv.cmd /traceon /tracegc

5)vsperfcmd /start:trace /output:test.vsp /launch:myapp.exe

and I get the following error:

Error VSP1335: Could not launch myapp.exe. This is an instrumented application - no sampling is allowed

Now in case is would run vsperfcmd without launching the app, and if I launch it automatically, the performance tool would in-fact run, but the performance report wouldn't show me the function names, just their memory addresses like I don't have my symbols set up. I've tried pointing to the symbols from vs when I open the performance report, but it doesn't seem to help either...

Comment: What does "Windows 7 WM" mean?

Comment: Sorry it was meant to be VM as in Virtual Machine. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: When a command line tool shows you `Usage: blabla` then it is trying to remind you that you got the command wrong and shows you what it expects.  The `filename` argument is not optional.

Comment: From MSDN: "If the usage information for vsinstr.exe is displayed, everything is set up correctly." but to make sure I've also tried the command like so: >vsinstr c:\localcache\somefile.vsp

Result:
Error VSP1022: The file image 'c:\localcache\somefile.vsp' could not be found.

Comment: `vsinstr` isn't the profiler, it *instruments* existing binaries, ie dlls and exes. *After* you instrument a binary, you can run it with the profiler to collect data in a`.vsp` file. The error messages are pretty clear. Even the one about trying to run sampling on an instrumented binary - you just instrumented it with `vsinstr`, sampling would be useless. Either use the command-line option for instrumented profiling, or simply don't instrument the binaries

Comment: and what is the command-line option for instrumented profiling? i was pretty sure vsperfcmd /start:trace is the command line option for instrumented profiling (and vsperfcmd /start:sample is the option for sample profiling) ps.: I didn't say vsinstr.exe is the profiler, I said exactly what you did.

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255420.aspx) for `/Start` you'll see that it isn't combined with the `/Launch` parameter. Try running `/Launch` separately

Comment: I tried, it makes no difference, I get the same error.

Comment: as I said, I can make it run if i run vsperfcmd without /launch and i launch the application manually, it starts, just int the .vsp files I can't get the symbols loaded so I don't get any function names, just memory addresses. I was trying to run it in one go in hopes it makes a difference, and to demonstrate the error I'm getting, because it makes no sense to me that it doesn't allow me to trace an instrumented application.

Comment: The profiler works. Instrumentation works. It's not only that I've used it multiple times -  if such a major component was broken it would have been noticed a long time ago. Just start profiling from inside Visual Studio to assure yourself that the profiler isn't broken. Check what you are doing wrong. Each comment reveals yet another wrong step or missing piece. Now you say that you are missing the symbols - *are* the symbols in the same folder? If not, did you tell the profiler where to find them?

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't I just don't know how to use it?! Profiling works when I'm using it from VS, but that is not what I'm trying to do. I feel you are not helping at all... instead of saying "Each comment reveals yet another wrong step or missing piece." you could reveal the wrong steps to or missing pieces to me as well. So unless you have something meaningful to say please stop commenting..